# How can I tie in Spring Data with Jersey 2?

Tags: web-applications, spring-data, jersey-2.0

In this project:
https://github.com/jstemen/json-to-db

I've been able to link Jersey 2 to Spring data in the following way:

```
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
/**
* Register JAX-RS application components.
*/
    @Inject
    public MyApplication(ServiceLocator serviceLocator) {
        //ToDo: find a way to have Jersey better interface with Spring

        //Pull bean out of Spring
        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        Rest rest = ctx.getBean(Rest.class);

        //Link pulled out Spring bean Jersey's DI framework
        DynamicConfiguration dc = Injections.getConfiguration(serviceLocator);
        Injections.addBinding(
                Injections.newBinder(rest)
                        .to(Rest.class),
                dc);

        dc.commit();//Don't forget to commit

        register(Rest.class); //Mark Rest class as an REST endpoint to Jersey
    }
}
```

However, it's not very eloquent.  Is there anyway that I can have my Web.xml load up Jersey 2 and Spring and have the Spring beans automatically mapped to into the Jersey REST endpoints?  It would be awesome if someone branched my repo and shared it to demonstrate how to do this better!

Answer (score 0):

Jersey 2 comes with an extension for integrating with Spring, see https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/spring.html

This works well, and our Spring components are autowired directly into our resource with field injection, like this:

```
@Component
@Path("/")
public class FooResource {
    @Autowired
    private SomeComponent someComponent;

    protected FooResource() {}

    @GET
    public String bar() {
        return "foobar";
    }
}
```

In your class that extends `ResourceConfig`, you simply do `register(FooResource.class)`! See the documentation and [Spring DI example](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/2.7/examples/helloworld-spring-webapp) for details.